# Ubuntu says "failed to finalize dm services, ignoring" before shutdown

Tags: 15.10, shutdown

When the system shuts down, I see the message "Failure-finalizing DM device."

What is this DM device, and how can I solve the problem?

I can use the PC without problems, but when I shut it down, Ubuntu says this message before it turns off.

Comment: I have the same issue in Kubuntu 20.04. You posted this question in 2016? Wow, still no replies.